# Xpath result vs. xs:assert result

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I am using oXygen XML Editor 16.1 using SaxonEE set for XML Schema 1.1 for these tests.

I want to insure that elements in a complexType that is a restriction of a base complexType, have the same number of enumerations. (Code below)

The sample complexType (bottom of post) should fail this assert:

```
<xs:assert test="count(//xs:element[@name='id-name']//xs:enumeration)  
eq count(//xs:element[@name='issuer']//xs:enumeration) 
and
count(//xs:element[@name='issuer']//xs:enumeration) 
eq count(//xs:element[@name='assignor']//xs:enumeration)"></xs:assert>
```

because assignor has three enumerations and the other elements have two. Whether I put this in the base complexType or the restricted complexType it still shows the restriction as a valid schema.

If I execute this

```
count(//xs:element[@name='id-name']//xs:enumeration) 
  eq count(//xs:element[@name='issuer']//xs:enumeration) and
count(//xs:element[@name='issuer']//xs:enumeration) 
  eq count(//xs:element[@name='assignor']//xs:enumeration)
```

in the XPath editor it fails​ (returns false)​ as expected as well as passes ​(returns true) ​when all three have two enumerations.

Sample restriction:

```
 <xs:complexType name='mytype' xml:lang='en-US'>
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:restriction base='myBaseType'>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs='1' minOccurs='1' name='id-name'>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
              <xs:enumeration value='URI'></xs:enumeration>
              <xs:enumeration value='ID Number'></xs:enumeration>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs='1' minOccurs='1' name='issuer'>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
              <xs:enumeration value='Owner'/>
              <xs:enumeration value='Owner'/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs='1' minOccurs='1' name='assignor'>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
              <xs:enumeration value='Owner'/>
              <xs:enumeration value='Owner'/>
              <xs:enumeration value='Owner'/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

'myBaseType' is in another schema that is 'included' in this one. That complexType looks like this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="myBaseType">
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="someType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id-name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="issuer" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="assignor" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="count(//xs:element[@name='id-name']//xs:enumeration) eq count(//xs:element[@name='issuer']//xs:enumeration) and
      count(//xs:element[@name='issuer']//xs:enumeration) eq count(//xs:element[@name='assignor']//xs:enumeration)
      "></xs:assert>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

What am I missing? Can't I establish asserts on a restriction complexType or do asserts only get evaluated for instance data? It seems to me that since 'mytype' is a restriction of 'myBaseType' then the assert should be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you anticipate at the end of your question, the scope for assertions is the XML document instance governed by the XSD, not the XSD itself.  If you wish to make assertions about the XSD itself, you'd have to create a meta-xsd that treated the original XSD as an XML document.

You could start with the [XML Schema schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd).  However, you should instead consider using [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) assertions, which will probably work better for selective enforcement of constraints.  I've used Schematron over XSDs to enforce organizational conventions and found it to be a viable approach for checking compliance with adopted policy.

---

### Update per OP comments

> '*If you wish to make assertions about the XSD itself, you'd have to
>   create a meta-xsd that treated the original XSD as an XML document*' --
>   Yes, that is what I did.

No, that is not what you've done.  You're trying to make assertions against the XSD from the same XSD that is validating your XML document instance.  The fact that it's a separate XSD brought in via `xsd:include` changes nothing; it's still only a domain XSD, not a meta XSD of the domain XSD.  What I said was that you would have to have a meta XSD, meaning a separate XSD that validates your domain XSD.  You've underestimated the complexity involved in such a task.  If you're not starting from the XML Schema schema, you're not realizing what a meta XSD has to do.

> I really prefer to not use schematron, if this can be done with XSD
>   1.1 then why add another element of complexity?

Because the complexity of enforcing spot-constraints via Schematron or some other technique is actually *lower* than the complexity of validating all of XSD via XSD and then tacking on some assertions to cover the spot-constraints.  Further, XSD 1.1's assertion facilities are considerably more restricted than Schematron's assertions.

Comment: 'If you wish to make assertions about the XSD itself, you'd have to create a meta-xsd that treated the original XSD as an XML document'  --  Yes, that is what I did.  As I said, the complexType with the enumerations is a restriction of a complexType from the schema where I put the assert.  I really prefer to not use schematron, if this can be done with XSD 1.1 then why add another element of complexity? The goal is for users to be able to create restricted schemas from the base schema but be required to have the same number of enumerations for each element in the restricted type.

Comment: The original post has been updated to show the myBaseType from the included schema.

Comment: @TimCook It's important to understand that an XSD cannot validate itself - much in the same way as humans find it hard to eat themselves (apologies for this horrible analogy). If you understand XML in general and XPath in particular, Schematron is not a big deal - it's really easy to use. P.s. Oxygen has good support for Schematron, there are even some predefined scenarios.

Comment: Right, I understand that an XSD cannot be used to validate itself.  However, since the content of a complexType that is a restriction of a complexType from an included XSD is most certainly validated against the base type being restricted.  This only seems to not be working for asserts. I thought I might have made a mistake in setting the context in the assert. But couldn't find it. Sure Saxon and(presumably Xerces)has Schematron support. Can Schematron rules exist in same XSD file?I am using oXygen, but the result of this research must be more generally useful and not tied to specific tools.

Comment: Can Schematron rules exist in same XSD file? == Yes. So. I'll investigate adding Schematron.